# ImageMagick - quoted numbers as convert label argument causes the command to fail

Tags: linux, command, imagemagick, label

my shell hangs on this command:

```
/usr/local/bin/convert -size 298x71 -background black -fill white -stroke none -gravity center -trim -interline-spacing 0 -font /home/amazingw/public_html/live/fonts/Phillies.ttf label:'150' png:-
```

The shell just sits there until i press ctrl+c. If I add any letter to the label: argument the command runs fine and I get output.
The font is there but it is missing the number characters in the definition.
Could that cause my command to fail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like an issue related to input at the console, I am assuming you are using Bash.

If this is the case, Bash is trying to interpret the quotes and is waiting for other input.

after reviewing the imagemagick website for "label:"

```
Label - Simple Text Label

Basic Labels

Creating a font image using a "label:" image, 
is the more typical way of drawing a font
quickly in ImageMagick...
```

It goes on and gives many examples...

```
convert -background lightblue -fill blue \
      -font Candice -pointsize 72 label:Anthony \
      label.gif
```

None of the examples show single quotes.

I would assume between Bash and ImageMagick's convert program, there is some error on interpretation of input from the console.

I would suggest trying your same command without quotes

```
/usr/local/bin/convert -size 298x71 -background black -fill white -stroke none -gravity center -trim -interline-spacing 0 -font /home/amazingw/public_html/live/fonts/Phillies.ttf label:150 png:-
```

I would also take a quick look at the [Bash manual about single quotes](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Single-Quotes) too.

Comment: I tried both using double and no quotes. No difference at all. It will work if I add a letter to the label - label:'a150' for example.

Comment: wow that definately sounds like a parsing issue, I would have to see the code to confirm, but it seems there is a bug with the version of imagemagick you have. what version might that be?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to test using a modified version of the font which contained the digits. Command went smoothly and an output image was returned. This pretty much narrows it down to an ImageMagick problem with handling labels. Looks like if the label is made out only of characters which are missing in the font (the resulting output image would be empty) - in that case ImageMagick hangs until ctrl+c is pressed - especially problematic as I'm running this from php's proc_open.